# How can a Windows Service interact with a Winforms Application through WCF?

Tags: .net, winforms, wcf, windows-services

I have a Windows Service running a self-hosted WCF service, which returns to the calling client data from a serial port.

Now I need to display this serial data in a Winforms Application through a push model -my service must push this serial data to winforms, maybe through events?

Any pointers to the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If WCF is the only way i'd look into the Duplex Binding for the behaviour you describe. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx

Comment: Look at callbacks.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731935.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could use WCF callbacks

- http://idunno.org/archive/2008/05/29/wcf-callbacks-a-beginners-guide.aspx
- http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=721
- http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/38814

or if you wanted to do this as a web approach you could use SignalR:

- http://signalr.net/

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to accomplish this: (1) Implement a service in your WinForms application that your Windows service connects to; and (2) Callbacks.